# Why .net project do not have the designer.cs?

Tags: .net

I opened a .net project of my colleague. But the project is weird that there is no any .aspx.designer.cs file, but only have .aspx.cs file. I would like to right click on the aspx file and choose the "Convert to application" button. But there no such button, why would this happen?

Comment: Is this a web site "project"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the project created as a "Web Site" rather than a "Web Application"? Web sites don't get designer files.